# Jetty 9 and GzipHandler

Tags: java, jetty, gzip

I'm trying to configure a Jetty 9 server to serve data Gzip compressed. Unfortunatelly I can't find any description that fits to my use case.
I think I have to use the new GzipHandler instead of the GzipFilter (starting from Jetty 9.3 the GzipFilter is just an dummy).

My setup is a WAR file which is deployed on a Jetty 9 installation or will be run by the maven-jetty-plugin. So this is no embedded Jetty.
Currently I just have an `jetty-env.xml` in `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF`. There are no other Jetty related config files.
I would appreciate a setup which doesn't need any changes on the Jetty installation. So it should be possible to enable the compression just by additional configuration in the WAR file.
I also like to compress static (files from `/src/main/resources/` and Webjars) and dynamic (generated by Jersey) content.

I hope that someone already did such an setup and can give me some hint.

Regards,
Johannes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Jetty Distribution Solution

If using the `jetty-distribution`, go add the `gzip` module to your configured `${jetty.base}`

eg:

```
$ cd /path/to/mybase
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar --add-to-start=gzip
```

You have now added the `GzipHandler` to that configuration of the server.

Look at the contents of your `/path/to/mybase/start.ini` for configuration options.

### Some Background

Since the introduction of Servlet 3.1 and the new Async I/O features it brings, the `GzipFilter` based approach is no longer possible.

The implementation of Gzip support in Jetty is now based on a Container HTTP Output Interceptor pattern.  This means `GzipHandler` has to be defined at a point in the Jetty Handler tree before your WebApp and its `WebAppContext` even exists.

This also means that you cannot add `GzipHandler` via `WEB-INF/web.xml` or anything contained within the WAR file, as this is far far to late in the lifecycle of the server to add the `GzipHandler`.

It is not possible to add `GzipHandler` *safely* from an embedded `WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml`, as the `WebAppContext` is the only thing you can safely manipulate from that file.

### Handler Tree Example

You have 2 webapps being deployed: `foo.war` and `baz.war`

This is the Server handler tree when not using Gzip ...

```
Server
  +-- .getHandler()
        +-- HandlerCollection (id="Handlers")
              +-- ContextHandlerCollection (id="Contexts")
              |     +-- WebAppContext "/foo" (foo.war)
              |     +-- WebAppContext "/baz" (baz.war)
              +-- DefaultHandler
```

This is the Server handler tree when GzipHandler is in the mix

```
Server
  +-- .getHandler()
        +-- GzipHandler
              +-- HandlerCollection (id="Handlers")
                    +-- ContextHandlerCollection (id="Contexts")
                    |     +-- WebAppContext "/foo" (foo.war)
                    |     +-- WebAppContext "/baz" (baz.war)
                    +-- DefaultHandler
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is not 100% what I'm looking for. I was looking for a solution where I don't need to modify the existing Jetty installation, just by adding a config file or some Java code to my WAR file.

Comment: Not sure that's possible, the GzipHandler is not a Servlet spec feature or implementation, its a container feature.   In the past the GzipFilter could just be added, but since Servlet 3.1 and the existence of Async I/O features in the Servlet spec, a filter based approach is no longer possible.